# Quarkus: how do I mock the smallrye-graphql-client using Mockito?

Tags: unit-testing, graphql, mockito, quarkus, smallrye

I am having some issues trying to mock the smallrye-graphql-client in my unit tests.
I thought it would be a process similar to mocking the RestClient https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/9630
but it doesn't work that way.

GraphQL client:

```
@GraphQLClientApi(configKey = "graphql-client")
public interface SomeGraphQLClient {
    @Query("accounts")
    List<Account> getAccounts();
}
```

Test:

```
@QuarkusTest
public final class SomeGraphQLClientTest {
    @InjectMock()
    SomeGraphQLClient client;

    @BeforeEach
    void setup() {
        when(client.getAccounts()).thenReturn(... list of accounts...);
    }

    @Test
    public void someTest() {
        ...
    }
}
```

application.yaml

```
  ...
  smallrye-graphql-client:
    graphql-client:
      url: http://localhost:8081/graphql
```

Error message:

```
Invalid use of io.quarkus.test.junit.mockito.InjectMock - the injected bean does not declare a CDI normal scope but: javax.inject.Singleton.
```

How can I mock the smallrye-graphql-client in Quarkus?

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: I admit in Quarkus team we haven't really thought about this yet. Support for mocking of injected GraphQL clients will probably need some code changes. For the time being, would you be able to do this without injecting pre-configured clients, but instead build your own mocks manually, using `Mockito.mock(SomeGraphQLClient.class)` and so?

Comment: I already did that and I went a little further... Now I am testing a mutation and I am getting `Query failed to validate`